# How do I calculate how much time has passed since the most recent block (via blockchain.info's api)?

Tags: javascript, bitcoin, blockchain

I have managed to get the websocket connection working, and am receiving data from `ping_block` and `blocks_sub`. However, I am having difficulty calculating the difference between the current date and block date received from `blockchain.info`'s api. Can anyone help with the code for calculating how much time has elapsed since the most recent block?

Also, how do I keep the connection open so that it updates the innerHTML object?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var wsUri = "wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv";
var output;

function init()
{
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    initWebSocket();
}

function initWebSocket()
{
    //  init blockchain websocket (activity, blocks)
    var blockchain = new WebSocket('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv');

    blockchain.onerror = function (error){ console.log('connection.onerror',error); };

    blockchain.onopen = function () 
    {
        writeToScreen("Connection to blockchain.info succesful.");
        blockchain.send( JSON.stringify( {"op":"ping_block"} ) );
        blockchain.send( JSON.stringify( {"op":"blocks_sub"} ) );       //  subscribe to new blocks
    };

    blockchain.onmessage = function (message) 
    {
        var response = JSON.parse(message.data);

        var date = new Date(0);
        date.setUTCSeconds( response.x.time );

        if( response.op == "utx")
        {
            var amount = 0;

            for(var i=0;i<response.x.out.length;i++) 
                amount += response.x.out[i].value;

            //  amount is in satoshi
            //  1 BTC = 100,000,000 Satoshi 


([url='https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/activity)']https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/activity)[/url]
            response.amount = amount / 100000000;
            response.type = TYPE_TRANSACTION;
            response.index = index++;
            response.date = date;
        }
        else if( response.op == "block" )
        {
            response.type = TYPE_BLOCK;

            response.date = date;

        }

        if( DEBUG ) 
            console.log( response.op, response );

        response.date = date;

        writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">Most recent block found      
on: </span>' + response.date);

    };
}


function writeToScreen(message)
{
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
}

//  constants
var TYPE_TRANSACTION = "transaction";
var TYPE_TRADE = "trade";
var TYPE_BLOCK = "block";
var MINUTE = 1000*60;
var HOUR = MINUTE*60;
var MIN_MINUTES = 1;
var MAX_MINUTES = 10;
var DEBUG = true;
var activity = [];
var index = 0;

 window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Comment: You have not provided any code samples or example data that you have to work with. Can you output the date object you received from the api? Are you able to parse that into a date object?

Comment: added current code. not sure how to go about getting the current time in the right format to compare to the timestamp of the most recent block.